# How can I use typeorm aggregators MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, nosql, typeorm

```
const query = await manager.createQueryBuilder(MyModel, 'MyModel');
query.select(['COUNT(someColumn) as nameOfSummedColumn']);
query.groupBy('someOtherColumn');
query.orderBy('someOtherColumn', 'DESC');
query.limit(limit);
query.getRawMany();
```

How can I use aggregators with typeorm to translate this SQL query to NoSQL(MongoDB) query?